# language analyzer not working with span query elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index **my_index** and a type **my_type**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "my_text": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "spanish"                 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then I want to search for 2 or more words, with, or without gaps but in the specified order.

For that I wrote the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "span_near": {
      "clauses": [
        {
          "span_term": {
            "my_text": "creación"
          }
        },
        {
          "span_term":  {
            "my_text": "fundación"
          }
        }
      ],
      "slop":4,
      "in_order": true
    }
  }    
}
```

The query is not producing results. But if i search "creacion" and "fundacion" (without diacritics) the query show results. 
*If i do a phrase_query "creación de una fundación" produces results*, so i think there is not support for language analyzers in span queries?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Curious if asciifolding filter helps? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/asciifolding-token-filter.html

Comment: In **phrase_query** works with and without diacritics and it finds stems too. Thanks for the tip, do you think it can be done?

Comment: Use `match_phrase` instead, potentially with a `slop`(for the gaps)

Comment: Thanks for the response Val but `match_phrase` doesnt take order into account if slop is present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Span queries are NOT analyzed, nor stemmed. They are LOW level queries exposed by the API and you need to know how it is stored before u do the SPAN query.